# Why is there only one non-strict function from Int to Int?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, computer-science

According to this [article](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Denotational_semantics#Non-Strict_and_Strict_Languages) on denotational semantics for Haskell there is only one non-strict (non-bottom prreserving) function from Int to Int.

to quote:

> it happens that there is only one prototype of a non-strict function of type Integer -> Integer:
>
> one x = 1
>
> Its variants are constk x = k for every concrete number k. Why are these the only ones possible? Remember that one n can be *no less* defined than one ⊥. As Integer is a flat domain, both must be equal.

Essentially it says that the only non-strict functions of that type signature can only be the constant functions. I don't follow this argument. I'm also unsure what is meant by a *flat domain*, the rest of the article leads to believe that it simply means that the poset of values has only one node: bottom.

Does something similar occur for function going from A->A, or A->B? That is they must be constant functions?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The intuition is that a lazy function can't inspect its argument here without forcing it (and hence become strict).  If you don't inspect your argument you have to be `const`

The real answer in *monotonicity*.  If you think of semantic domains as posets where the ordering relationship is one of "defined-ness", all functions are order preserving.  Why? Since all bottoms are created equal, and looping forever is the same thing as bottom, a non monotonic function would be one that solves the halting problem.

Okay, so why does that imply it `const` creates the only lazy functions?  Well, say pick an arbitrary function `f` such that

```
f :: Integer -> Integer
f ⊥ = y
```

since `⊥ <= x` for all `x`, it must be that `y <= f x`.  If `y` is a non bottom value, then the only solution to that inequality is `f x = y`

Edit: The reason why this argument holds for types like `Integer` and `Bool` but not for types like `[a]` is the last step: `Integer` in a sense only has a single `⊥` in it.  That is, all Integers are equally defined except for `⊥`.  On the other hand, `⊥ < (⊥:⊥)` while `(⊥:⊥) < (⊥:[])` and `(⊥:⊥) < (⊥:(⊥:⊥)) < (⊥:(⊥:(⊥:⊥))) < ...` whats more, `(⊥:⊥)  < ('a':⊥)`.  That is, the semantic domain of `[a]` is rich enough that `y <= f x` with `y =/= ⊥` does not imply that `f x = y`.

Comment: How can an ordering on a poset be 'defined'? Surely this means that the ordering relationship *changes* in time as more values become defined? Is a semantic domain the same as a type? Why does a non-monotone function solve the halting problem? Does this argument hold if the semantic domain holds only a finite number of values, say Bool? I can see why y<=f x, but I don't see the reverse that y>=f x.

Comment: ok,thanks. the article actually answers these questions earlier on.

Answer (score 17):

Any function on `Integer` that is not `const k` for some constant `k` must inspect its argument. You can't partially inspect an `Integer`, which <del>might be</del> is what is meant by it being a "flat domain". This is a consequence of how the semantics of `Integer` are defined in the Haskell specs, not something that follows from the core language's semantics.

By contrast, infinitely many non-strict functions of type `[a] -> [a]` exist for every type `a`, e.g. `take1`:

```
take1 (x:_) = [x]
```

To show non-strictness, define

```
ones = 1 : ones
```

In terms of denotational semantics, [[`ones`]] = ⊥. But `take1 ones` evaluates to `[1]`, so `take1` is non-strict. So are `take2 (x:y:_) = [x,y]`, `take10`, etc.

If you want non-strict, non-constant functions on integers, you need a different representation of the integers than `Integer`, e.g.:

```
data Bit = Zero | One
newtype BinaryInt = I [Bit]
```

If we interpret the list in an `I` as a "little-endian" binary integer, then the function

```
mod2 (I [])       =  I []
mod2 (I (lsb:_))  =  I [lsb]
```

is non-strict.

Comment: interesting. I find it a little odd that strictness may or may not imply constness depending on the underlying implementation of integer. But I suspect that your last example isn't an integer, its just that it can be *interpreted* as such.

Comment: @MoziburUllah The same goes for Haskell's built-in `Integer`, of course -- it's just bit patterns in the end :)

Comment: @MoziburUllah If you do not like the example, take data Nat = Zero | Succ Nat. Here, you can then have non-strict functions like inc = Succ